# Weird Rails 3.2 Apache Passenger 500 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a new rails app, it works locally, and works on my test server, but doesn't work on the production server. The odd part is that it works in some of the routes, but not others.

I am using active admin and all of the forms I setup behind active_admin logins are working correctly, however all of my public views and the home page keeps showing 500 errors.

The configuration on test and production are nearly identical and even though I have logging setup in my vhost.conf, it's not logging anything in either the application log or the apache log.

I'm assuming this is a permission or gem issue, but can't seem to track down anything causing it.

**Edit: Also I should note that all of my assets are serving up correctly when I go them. I can access them directly via URL and they work.**

Rails console works as well with all of my objects. I've spent a lot of time on this today and looked through a lot of similar questions with no luck. Any suggestions on how to debug this would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here is  my .conf entry for this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app_admin/public/
    <Directory /var/www/app_admin/public>
                            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    ServerName www.mydomainname.com
    ServerAlias mydomainname.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/app_admin/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/app_admin/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: please post the apache's site file containing "<VirtualHost>..", and the `$ ls -altr` result from the rails app folder.

Comment: Not sure what level I should show the -altr at:

Comment: Here is the app root: 
    drwxr-xr-x 16 apache apache 4096 Apr  6 14:31 app_admin

Comment: Who should generally own the folder that Phusion runs out of? I've tried changing it, but on test server I still have it as root.

Comment: Ok, so I've just setup a new app from scratch on the production server with one view. It doesn't work either, I'm pretty sure this has to be a server issue and not related to the app.

Answer (score 0):

please try adding a new line `Options -MultiViews` to the "Directory' node.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  #...
  <Directory /var/www/app_admin/public>
     AllowOverride all 
     Options -MultiViews  # add this line 
  </Directory>
  #...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that. Unfortunately no change. Still serving up active_admin files, nothing else.

Comment: I am seeing cache misses in error.log for whatever route I try to hit in.
Like this one: 
**cache: [GET /builders] miss**

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this before.

What (I believe) caused the weirdness was Apache picking up resources from Development instead of Production due to rails s being executed instead of RAILS_ENV=production rails s. Not sure how, but it managed to pick up the PID from Dev.

I ended up rebooting the server, avoiding running any sort of rails s command, and it worked after that.

Big shrug on that one.